# MySQL Complex Check with dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called Offers in which I have several offers:

```
ID  | List Name | Arrival    | Depart      | Price
1   | Plus      | 12 August  | 18 August   | $ 100.00
2   | Plus      | 19 August  | 25 August   | $ 120.00
3   | Plus      | 26 August  | 1 September | $  80.00
4   | Weekend   | 11 August  | 13 August   | $  50.00
5   | Weekend   | 18 August  | 20 August   | $  60.00
6   | Weekend   | 25 August  | 27 August   | $  40.00
```

Then I have a guest in my hotel which has a check-in and check-out date.

In need to find all the offers with the same List Name that cover all the days of my vacation's guest (from check-in date to check-out date).

Example
If my guest spends his time in my hotel from the 13th of August to the 20th of August I need to be returned only ids 1 and 2.

If my guest spends his time in my hotel from the 13th of August to the 27th of August I need to be returned only ids 1, 2, and 3. That's because the ids 6 and 7 cover only weekend and not all the days between check-in and check-out dates.

If my guest spends his time in my hotel from the 18th of August to the 20th of August I need to be returned only ids 1, 2 and 5.

Comment: Wait...do you have an _HTML_ table or a SQL table?

Comment: It's a SQL Table, I used HTML just to let you people check the table in a better way...

Comment: It's not a better way.  Please edit the question so that it actually appears as a SQL table.

Comment: is it now better?

Comment: Now I can see your data, but may I ask why rows 1, 2, and 5 match a stay from August 18 to 20?

Comment: Don't store '$' ! Store dates as dates. And see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for logic like this:

```
select o.*
from offers o
where o.arrival <= $arrival and o.depart >= $depart;
```

`$arrival` and `$depart` are the dates for your guest.

Comment: It's not that simple, I changed something, please read again the main message. I apologize for this incovenient...

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/367263/11)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE offers
    (`ID` int, `Arrival` date, `Depart` date, `Price` float)
;

INSERT INTO offers
    (`ID`, `Arrival`, `Depart`, `Price`)
VALUES
    (1, '2016-08-12', '2016-08-18', 100.00),
    (2, '2016-08-19', '2016-08-25', 120.00),
    (3, '2016-08-26', '2016-09-01', 80.00),
    (4, '2016-08-11', '2016-08-13', 50.00),
    (5, '2016-08-18', '2016-08-20', 60.00),
    (6, '2016-08-25', '2016-08-27', 40.00)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select *
from offers
where (((arrival >= '2016-08-13' and arrival <= '2016-08-20') or
        (depart >= '2016-08-13' and depart <= '2016-08-20')) 
       and datediff(depart,arrival) = 6) 
or
(arrival = '2016-08-13' and depart = '2016-08-20'
and datediff(depart,arrival) = 2)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/367263/11/0)**:

```
| ID |                  Arrival |                   Depart | Price |
|----|--------------------------|--------------------------|-------|
|  1 | August, 12 2016 00:00:00 | August, 18 2016 00:00:00 |   100 |
|  2 | August, 19 2016 00:00:00 | August, 25 2016 00:00:00 |   120 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select *
from offers
where (((arrival >= '2016-08-13' and arrival <= '2016-08-27') or
        (depart >= '2016-08-13' and depart <= '2016-08-27')) 
       and datediff(depart,arrival) = 6) 
or
(arrival = '2016-08-13' and depart = '2016-08-27'
and datediff(depart,arrival) = 2)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/367263/11/1)**:

```
| ID |                  Arrival |                      Depart | Price |
|----|--------------------------|-----------------------------|-------|
|  1 | August, 12 2016 00:00:00 |    August, 18 2016 00:00:00 |   100 |
|  2 | August, 19 2016 00:00:00 |    August, 25 2016 00:00:00 |   120 |
|  3 | August, 26 2016 00:00:00 | September, 01 2016 00:00:00 |    80 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
select *
from offers
where (((arrival >= '2016-08-18' and arrival <= '2016-08-20') or
        (depart >= '2016-08-18' and depart <= '2016-08-20')) 
       and datediff(depart,arrival) = 6) 
or
(arrival = '2016-08-18' and depart = '2016-08-20'
and datediff(depart,arrival) = 2)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/367263/11/2)**:

```
| ID |                  Arrival |                   Depart | Price |
|----|--------------------------|--------------------------|-------|
|  1 | August, 12 2016 00:00:00 | August, 18 2016 00:00:00 |   100 |
|  2 | August, 19 2016 00:00:00 | August, 25 2016 00:00:00 |   120 |
|  5 | August, 18 2016 00:00:00 | August, 20 2016 00:00:00 |    60 |
```

Comment: You can put `(arrival between '2016-08-13' and '2016-08-20' or depart between '2016-08-13' and '2016-08-20')` instead of `((arrival >= '2016-08-13' and arrival <= '2016-08-20') or (depart >= '2016-08-13' and depart <= '2016-08-20'))`

Comment: What do constants 6 and 2 represent?

Comment: It's used to determine if the offer is for a week-enk only. As I understand week-end offers are only for those that take that week-end (your 3rd example)